# Include <arrayobject.h> header path to compile C python extension in build pipeline using cibuildwheels

Tags: python, numpy, build, github-actions, python-c-api

I'm developing a python package that contains a C extension. I want to deploy a release for each operating system (linux, windows, macOS) using [cibuildwheel](https://github.com/pypa/cibuildwheel). The C extension uses the `arrayobject.h` header (from numpy). In order to use this header locally I set the enviroment variable `C_INCLUDE_PATH` and I'm trying to do that in the builder action.

As I don't know "where" is that header in the cloud I find it using this command:

```bash
$(python -c 'import numpy, os; print(os.path.dirname(numpy.__file__))')/core/include/numpy
```

I've tried to set that enviroment variable using:

```ini
[tool.cibuildwheel]
environment = { C_INCLUDE_PATH="$(python -c 'import numpy, os; print(os.path.dirname(numpy.__file__))')/core/include/numpy" }
```

But it sais numpy is not installed, even when I've tried:

```ini
[tool.cibuildwheel]
before-build = [ "pip install numpy" ]
```

> I'm aware that I should use the `build-system.requires` but that didn't work either.

It seems that enviroment variables are setted before all.

I know i can use the `-I` flag and set the `CFLAG` variable but I'm afraid this will end up in the same mistake (evaluating the variable before instaling numpy).

So, how can I include this path? Is a better way to do this that I'm missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I got a [solution](https://github.com/pypa/cibuildwheel/discussions/1126#discussioncomment-2886666) from the cibuildwheel's discussion section and it worked for me (I'm using setuptools):

- Set `oldest-supported-numpy` as a build requirement in the `build-system.requires` section in the `pyproject.toml`
- Set the parameter `include_dirs=[np.get_include()]` for the Extension instance in the `setup.py`.

This way there is no need of setting any `before-build` command or any `environment` variable for the build pipline.